# Exoplayer2 DRM exception shouldWaitForKeys

Tags: android, drm, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Hi i'm switching my working DRM implementation from Exoplayer 1.x to Exoplayer 2.x but i have some exceptions and i can not playback the DRM licensed video. My drm session manager:

```
    protected DrmSessionManager<FrameworkMediaCrypto> generateDrmSessionManager() {
        // DRM is only supported on API 18 + in the ExoPlayer
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            return null;
        }

        // Widevine will capture the majority of use cases however playready is supported on all AndroidTV devices
        UUID uuid = C.WIDEVINE_UUID;
        final String licenseURL = "http://video.aaa";

        HttpMediaDrmCallback drmCallback =
                new HttpMediaDrmCallback(
                        licenseURL, buildHttpDataSourceFactory(false), KEY_REQUEST_PROPERTIES);

        try {
            return new DefaultDrmSessionManager<>(
                    uuid, FrameworkMediaDrm.newInstance(uuid), drmCallback, null, mainHandler, capabilitiesListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Unable to create a DrmSessionManager due to an exception", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I have the drmSession and then when HttpMediaDrmCallback executes

```
executePost(dataSourceFactory, url, request.getData(), requestProperties);
```

inside there is the call that causes the `onDrmSessionManagerError` (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) when calling:

```
HttpDataSource dataSource = dataSourceFactory.createDataSource();
```

at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.shouldWaitForKeys(MediaCodecRenderer.java:735)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.feedInputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:676)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:511)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:479)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:308)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                                                 Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSession$DrmSessionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.onError(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:604)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.onKeysError(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:599)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.onKeyResponse(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:559)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.access$900(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:50)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager$PostResponseHandler.handleMessage(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:679)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
                                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkNotEmpty(Assertions.java:138)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:148)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory.createDataSourceInternal(DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory.java:81)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory.createDataSourceInternal(DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory.java:22)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$BaseFactory.createDataSource(HttpDataSource.java:176)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.HttpMediaDrmCallback.executePost(HttpMediaDrmCallback.java:139)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.HttpMediaDrmCallback.executeKeyRequest(HttpMediaDrmCallback.java:134)
                                                                                                    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager$PostRequestHandler.handleMessage(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:702)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

I do not know why it crashes, as in my Exoplayer 1.x implementation was working good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is caused by the userAgent string being null or zero length here:

```js
public DefaultHttpDataSource(String userAgent, Predicate<String> contentTypePredicate,
      TransferListener<? super DefaultHttpDataSource> listener, int connectTimeoutMillis,
      int readTimeoutMillis, boolean allowCrossProtocolRedirects,
      RequestProperties defaultRequestProperties) {
    this.userAgent = Assertions.checkNotEmpty(userAgent);  <---- Exception is here
    this.contentTypePredicate = contentTypePredicate;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.requestProperties = new RequestProperties();
    this.connectTimeoutMillis = connectTimeoutMillis;
    this.readTimeoutMillis = readTimeoutMillis;
    this.allowCrossProtocolRedirects = allowCrossProtocolRedirects;
    this.defaultRequestProperties = defaultRequestProperties;
  }
```

The userAgent is a combination of the application name and the ExoPlayer library version:

```js
/**
   * Returns a user agent string based on the given application name and the library version.
   *
   * @param context A valid context of the calling application.
   * @param applicationName String that will be prefix'ed to the generated user agent.
   * @return A user agent string generated using the applicationName and the library version.
   */
  public static String getUserAgent(Context context, String applicationName) {
    String versionName;
    try {
      String packageName = context.getPackageName();
      PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
      versionName = info.versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
      versionName = "?";
    }
    return applicationName + "/" + versionName + " (Linux;Android " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE
        + ") " + ExoPlayerLibraryInfo.VERSION_SLASHY;
  }
```

You can see examples of it being used and set in the demo application: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demo

There is also information about setting up the MediaPlayer in the documentation (https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html) which includes this example showing the userAgent being set:

```js
// Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
// Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
    Util.getUserAgent(context, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
// Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
// This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mp4VideoUri,
    dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
// Prepare the player with the source.
player.prepare(videoSource);
```

Comment: Not seems to be the causes..currently i'm setting the user agent properly.

Comment: @Billyjoker - if you take a look at the Stacktrace you can see the exception thrown 'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkNotEmpty(Assertions.java:138) at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource'. It may be that you set it but that it becomes reset or nulled before you use it, or that the wrong variable is passed mistakenly.

Comment: You were right!! The problem was that i created a DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory with my user agent with an empty value, but when i created a DefaultDataSourceFactory the user agent was right, but it raised the shouldWaitForKeys exception. So, i filled the empty user agent and works like a charm!! Many thanks